# Is the proof in "On Hilbert’s 8th Problem" published on Brazilian Journal of Probability and Statistics correct?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function

The article can be freely accessed [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/26496523?seq=1). The proof is only five pages. I am quite in doubt.

A new version (2021) of that paper can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02653).

Comment: Generally speaking we try to avoid "is this paper correct" type questions on the forum.   If you were to write up a specific argument in detail and ask about a specific step, that is the kind of question that would get a response here.  But blanket "please publicly referee this paper" questions do not get a positive reception.

Answer (score 5):

According to MR it has been retracted by the author, see Braz. J. Probab. Stat. 33 (2019). See also the MathReview for details on the proof.

Comment: Is there a published paper on the journal "Mathematical Review (AMS)" on this topic?

Comment: @HighGPA:  Math Reviews is not a journal.  They index published papers, and offer reviews of the papers.